# How does the Hardline Pro perk work?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I've heard a good amount of chatter about the Hardline pro perk, but I still can't wrap my head around how the pro perk works.

With Hardline Pro, when you get a care package, does it prompt you to see if you want to keep it and get another one?  Do you always get a better one the second time or is it random?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the care package drops you can see what is in it like normal. If you don't want what's in it you can tap X twice to reroll it.

From the wiki:

---

Hardline reduces all killstreak requirements by one. Its pro version allows the player to "re-roll" any killstreak crate by double-tapping the action button, which will change its contents randomly. A crate can only be re-rolled once, and will always change its content.
While not yet released, a patch announced on December 4, 2010 will restrict Hardline Pro's re-roll to Care Packages only. The SAM Turret, Sentry Gun, and Valkyrie Rocket crates will no longer be re-rollable, greatly limiting its usefulness.

---

The chances of getting something good are slightly better though. [Source](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Hardline)

Comment: Treyarch is currently working on a patch to allow the player to only re-roll on a care package.  It will not work on the sentry gun or SAM turret packages.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with shared packages? For instance, someone without hardline gets a care package and then can someone with hardline come and re-roll the care package?

Comment: If my above comment is true, then I've encountered a bug with this behavior where someone tried to re-roll my care package as I was capturing it and made the care package completely disappear and neither of us captured it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good video on youtube covering the odds of getting something better when re-rolling a care package. The Valkyre Rocket is the break even point.

[Youtube (WoodysGamertag) - When to reroll a care package](http://www.youtube.com/user/WoodysGamertag#p/u/10/BkiZ8eGbvYI)
[image: When to reroll a care package]